# Print data from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have next code which creates a print page with data from datagridview.

```
     Font print10B = new Font("Lucida Console", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font print8B = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
        Font print6B = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("   NOTA DE PLATA",print10B,Brushes.Black,10,10);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("-----------------------------------------", new Font(dataGridView1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 10, 70);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Produs   | Cant | Pret | Total ", print8B, Brushes.Black, 10, 100);
        int height = 0;
        int x = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["DenumireProdus"].Value.ToString(), print6B, Brushes.Black, x, 120+height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["produs_cantitate"].Value.ToString(), print6B, Brushes.Black, x+70, 120 + height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["produs_pret"].Value.ToString() , print6B, Brushes.Black, x+105, 120 + height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["produsvaloare"].Value.ToString(), print6B, Brushes.Black, x + 135, 120 + height);
            height += 20;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString("-----------------------------------------", new Font(dataGridView1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 10, dataGridView1.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total:  " + textBox1.Text+" RON", print10B, Brushes.Black,40, dataGridView1.Height + 10);
```

Until  here:

```
       e.Graphics.DrawString("-----------------------------------------", new Font(dataGridView1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 10, dataGridView1.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total:  " + textBox1.Text+" RON", print10B, Brushes.Black,40, dataGridView1.Height + 10);
```

The printer does not print the above part ( the last 2 drawstrings). Why ?

The printer page size is Proportional A4 (48mmx68mm)

Comment: did you try to print *only* bottom part?

Comment: Did you run out of space on the paper?

Comment: @CodyGray I think so , how can i see if i did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why cant you use Crystal reports ? or any other reporting tools, which may server better in your case.

[Tutorial for Crystal Reports](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm)